# Intercepting a planet by a rocket flying in straight line

Tags: orbital-motion, astronomy

There is a scenario: we have a planet in orbit and a rocket very far away from that planet. Our plan is to fly a straight line into a point on the planet's orbit where the rocket and the planet will meet at the same time. We are ignoring such aspects like gravity and propellant consumption.

What I think for this scenario, it all boils down to solve this function: $$d(\alpha) = | r(\alpha) - p(\alpha) | $$ where $r(\alpha)$ returns time for the rocket to reach a point on the orbit at true anomaly $\alpha$ and $p(\alpha)$ is the same for the planet. Obviously our goal is to find minimum of $d(\alpha)$ function (which preferably should be zero).

I can find what the $r(\alpha)$ function should be: it would be probably some positive sine/cosine function with a border case being a constant function (that is, when the rocket is directly above the center of an circular orbit).

What I can't find/decide is what kind of a function would be the $p(\alpha)$. I think it should be time to reach $\alpha$ and if the planet is *before* that point, then it is simple: it is a positive number telling how much time it needs to be at that point. But I'm absolutely not sure how to model that function for cases when the planet is *after* that point. Should it be negative? And if so, will be then exist a point where the functions "jumps" from negative values into positive values?

I'm aware of the fact that it is not an optimal way to intercept a planet. I'm doing it rather as an exercise. Also, probably there will be many of such that points where $d(\alpha)$ is zero.

**What I wish to know is**: what is the $p(\alpha)$ function or if the $d(\alpha)$ is an ascending/descending function (which makes me find an algorithm to search for $\alpha$ easier).

Comment: Rockets don't fly in straight lines.  EVERY object in space exerts the force of gravity on that rocket, and they do so in 3 dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  I'm reading you correctly, you want to do an interception in 3D.  For a straight line projectile, use an xyz system,  The planet starts on the x axis and moves in a circle in the xy plane: x = R cos(ωt) , y = R sin(ωt) , and z = 0.   The projectile starts on the z axis giving:  x = $v_{ox}$t , y = $v_{oy}$t ,  z = $z_o$ + $v_{oz}$t, and ${v_{ox}}^2$ + ${v_{oy}}^2$ + ${v_{oz}}^2$ =${v_o}^2$.  After a time t, both objects should have the same coordinates. You chose $v_o$. Then you have four equations and four unknowns: the time, and the three velocity components.  (With numbers, solver on an Excel spreadsheet can give you results.) (This solution is just for your "border case" , but it can be easily modified for other starting positions.)

Answer (score 1):

Although I accepted *R.W.Bird* answer (and I think it is a good answer) after some thinking I found yet another solution, which I want to share there.

First of all, I approached the problem at wrong angle (quite literally): instead of trying to find $\alpha$ I should try to find the time to reach the planet by the rocket.

So, here is the algorithm:

- **Step 1**: calculate the closest and the farthest point at the planet's orbit from the rocket's position: $d_c$ and $d_f$,
- **Step 2**: calculate time to reach above points (this could be as simple as $t_c = \frac{d_c}{v_0}$ and $t_f = \frac{d_f}{v_0}$)
- **Step 3**: for every time $t_i$ between $t_c$ and $t_f$:

  - Calculate the planet position at time $t_i$: $p(t_i)$,
  - Calculate how far the rocket can go after time $t_i$: $d_i$ (again, this could be as simple as $d_i = v_0 t_i$),
  - if the distance from $p(t_i)$ to the rocket is the same as (or close to) $d_i$, then return $t_i$ and stop the algorithm.

And that's it, the position $p(t_i)$ and time $t_i$ is our interception point.

### Note A: intercepting at the planet's $n$-th orbit

The algorithm tries to calculate the fastest interception point on the planet's orbit. If for some reason this point is unacceptable (because, for example, it requires our rocket to fly at impossible speed), you can calculate the interception point at the next $n$-th orbit.

To do so, just change $p(t_i)$ to $p(nT + t_i)$, where $T$ is the orbit's period and $n$ is which $n$-th orbit you want to calculate.

### Note B: speed up Step 3

In step 3, instead of iterating by every possible $t_i$ one can apply binary search algorithm instead:

- **Step 3.1**: set $t_i$ as $\frac{t_f - t_c}{2}$
- **Step 3.2**: calculate how far the rocket can go after time $t_i$: $d_i$
- **Step 3.3**: calculate planet's position at $t_i$: $p(t_i)$
- **Step 3.4**: if the distance from the rocket to $p(t_i)$ is:

  - *smaller than $d_i$*: set $t_c = t_i$ and go to *Step 3.1*,
  - *bigger than $d_i$*: set $t_f = t_i$ and go to *Step 3.1*,
  - *equal to or close enough to $d_i$*: return $t_i$ and stop the algorithm

### Note C: special case

There is a special case when the rocket is directly above the center of the planet's orbit and the orbit is perfectly circular (very improbable, but still). If that is the case, then the algorithm is:

- **Step 1**: chose any point at the planet's orbit $p$ and calculate the time for the rocket to reach that point $t$
- **Step 2**: calculate the position of the planet after time $t$ and return it: $p(t)$

The interception point is: $p(t)$ and $t$.

Comment: What prevents the interception from occurring after $t_f$?

Comment: @R.W.Bird because $t_f$ corresponds to the farthest point of the orbit *from the rocket perspective*, it means if we spend more time in flight than $t_f$ then we will go after that point. And because it is the farthest point, it means we pass the whole orbit and thus it is impossible to meet the planet after that.

Comment: Unless you are seeking a minimum time, the projectile can go slower and intercept at a later part of the orbit.